# Flutter save data using http after get location

Tags: flutter, http, geocoding

I'm new in Flutter. I got an issue where i cannot POST data using http after get location.

This is the code

```
void postData() async {
   prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

   bool isAutoCheckIn = prefs.getBool(helper.ISAUTO_CHECKIN) ?? false;

   var sessionId = prefs.getString(helper.SESSION_ID);
   var employeeId = prefs.getInt(helper.EMPLOYED_ID).toString();

   var _uri = Uri.parse(
       helper.CHECK_IN + employeeId);

   var header = {"session-id": sessionId!};

   try {
     if (valid) {
       Position position = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(
           desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.medium);

       var _center = LatLng(position.latitude, position.longitude);

       List<Placemark> p = await placemarkFromCoordinates(
           _center.latitude, _center.longitude);

       Placemark place = p[0];

       var address =
           "${place.street}, ${place.locality}, ${place.subAdministrativeArea}";

       var body = {
         "test": address          
       };

       final response = await http.post(_uri, headers: header, body: body);
       if (response.statusCode == 200) {
         dynamic _data = json.decode(response.body);
       }
     }
   } catch (err) {
     throw Exception(err);
   }
}
```

Problem comes after this code

```
List<Placemark> p = await placemarkFromCoordinates(            
   _center.latitude, _center.longitude);
```

It will never reach code below it. I am using `http: ^0.13.5 geolocator: ^7.7.1  geocoding: ^2.0.5`. Am I doing wrong here? Please kindly help me. Thank you

Comment: what error are you getting in the console ? Also, did you add the location permission and also you need to ask for use of location from user before accessing location

Comment: There is no error. Location is just fine. I can display it well. The problem is the code below it just like not executed @OMiShah